Is there a way to wait for response from a function before sending a response to my frontend?
I am building a logic to upload videos to cloudinary using node.js, next.js and multer package.
I have a mongodb document that I would like to store the video url and publicid of the video once cloudinary upload function completes.
This means that I would like to wait for the process to complete, sore it as part of my response before creating the document.
Unfortunately, I am unable to get this to work. The video upload takes time to complete. I would like to wait for the response to decide what to send back to the client.
Here is the cloudinary upload function:
export const largeFileUploader = async(props: {targetedFile: string})=>{
const {targetedFile} = props;

try {
   cloudinary.uploader.upload_large(targetedFile, 
    { resource_type: "video" , 
        chunk_size: 6000000, folder: 'folderName', upload_preset: 'presetName' }, 
    function(error, result) {
        console.log(error, 'error')
        if(error) throw 'Error encountered';
        
        return result
    });  
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
   throw 'file upload error';
};

};
I wrote another function that can be invoked in a route:
const imageUploadFunct = async(req: Request, res: Response, eventType: events)=>{   
    const files = req?.files as Express.Multer.File[];
    const imageUrl: string[] = [];
    const publicId: string[] = [];

  if(eventType === 'video_upload_event'){
    const uploadResponse = await largeFileUploader({targetedFile: file?.path}) as any;

    imageUrl.push(uploadResponse?.secure_url);
    publicId.push(uploadResponse?.public_id);

      if(file?.path){
         removeFile({filePath: file?.path});
       };
     return { imageUrl, publicId };
  }
};

Then in my controller, I have this:
export const httpUploadVideo = async (req: Request, res: Response)=>{

    try {
        const response = await imageUploaderFunc(req, res, 'video_upload_event');
        return res.status(200).json(response)
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json('Something went wrong, refresh your page or contact support');
    };

};
The cloudinary upload method takes time to complete the video upload before returning with response.  Before then, my client already got response from me. Now, I need the cloudinary response to send to my client but before it can be ready, my code has already returned and sent response to client.
How do I make my code to wait until cloudinary returns a response before I send a response to the client?
I know there can be option for me to update the mongoose database background wise when cloudinary sends a a feedback by building something like an event hook. But I dont really wish to follow that path.

The largeFileUploader function is async, but it doesn't await anything.  The asynchronous operation therein is using a callback rather than a Promise:
cloudinary.uploader.upload_large(
  targetedFile,
  { resource_type: "video", chunk_size: 6000000, folder: 'folderName', upload_preset: 'presetName' }, 
  function(error, result) {
    console.log(error, 'error')
    if(error)
      throw 'Error encountered';
    return result
  }
);

If the service provides an awaitable API, it is recommended to use that instead.  If they don't, one option is to wrap this callback structure in a Promise and return that so consuming code can await it.  For example:
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  cloudinary.uploader.upload_large(
    targetedFile,
    { resource_type: "video", chunk_size: 6000000, folder: 'folderName', upload_preset: 'presetName' }, 
    function(error, result) {
      console.log(error, 'error')
      if(error)
        reject('Error encountered'); // <-- reject the Promise
      resolve(result); // <-- resolve the Promise
    }
  );
});


I just checked your code carefully and almost correct, but you made some mistakes in largeFileUploader function. cloudinary.upload.upload_large is async function so you should use await here to waits uploading results from cloudinary. But you didn't used await and handled the result in callback of upload_large. In this case, the result will be returned once you already sent response to the client so it's wrong. I provide updated code for it.
export const largeFileUploader = async(props: {targetedFile: string})=> {
    const {targetedFile} = props;

    try {
        const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload_large(targetedFile, {
            resource_type: 'video',
            chunk_size: 6000000,
            folder: 'folderName',
            upload_preset: 'presetName',
        });

        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        throw new Error('file upload error');
    }
};


thanks for trying to help me. But it is still the same thing. It returns undefine immediately and later completes the process in background. I did exactly what you did here.

Oh... you mean, result is undefined? There is no error log?

Not an error. It simply returns result when it has not completed it process. I don't know if it is how the cloudinary method was designed or there is a way I can get it to work. I just want my client to get response only when result has completed it upload and return data. It returns undefine and after like 1 minute or there about, result returns the data. By then, my client already got a response but with an undefined data.

Oh, sorry. I don't understand well. You mean, you got undefined directly and then after 1 minute, you got correct result again from cloudinary?

Yes. Exactly. But I would want to wait until I get response from cloudinary before sending response to my client.

Very strange. how can you get result twice when you use await? Anyway, I will check your code again.

With the way you wrote it, the result does not return twice. It returns undefine. I console.log(result) right inside the cloudinary upload method and I can see that it returned undefined. Like I am expecting result.url from cloudinary but it does return undefine. However, few minutes later, the video gets uploaded on cloudinary. Using the way I wrote the code previously, I got to know that cloudinary result was still waiting to be resolved. I am wondering why await didn't wait for it to be resolved before providing me with undefine.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I found the correct solution. In cloudinary, it returns only a few details such as status and batch_id for tracking the upload. So to get full response, you need to set notification_url and will get the result via the url. It means, cloudinary support webhook notification method. So to notify the uploading result, I think you can implement websocket loigc so you will get the uploading result from cloudinary via webhook and then will send the result to the client with websocket.
